# Mutable variables and memory management in Python

Tags: python, cpython

I am trying to understand how Python memory management works. If I have an mutable variable, say a list:

```
x = ['x1', 'x2']
print(id(x))
```

then I will get a certain memory address. 
If I now modify x say `x.append('x3')`, the memory address is the same as before because lists are mutable data types. If, however, I change x with `x = x + ['x3']` and I print the address I get a different one. Why it is so? I mean, the `x` variable has still the same name and all I have done is to modify its content. Why does Python change the address of the variable in this case?

Comment: because it creates a new variable that it assigns to name `x`. You did not "just modify it's content". To modify the content do `x += ['x3']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when doing:

```
x = x + ['x3']
```

you're creating a *new* `list` which is assigned to `x`. The previous list held under the name `x` is lost and garbage collected (unless it was stored somewhere else).

The creation of a new element, even stored under the same name, results in a new identifier.

Also note that if you want to append `x3` (or another list) that is highly inefficient because of the copy of the original list to create another one. In your case, `x.append('x3')` is the fastest way, and `extend()` or `x += ['x3','x4','x5']` is the fastest way to append to (and mutate) an existing list with multiple elements at once.

(also note that `+=` mutates the list but when used on immutable types like `tuple`, it still creates another `tuple`)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are memory references in Python. When you say `x = x + ['x3']` it merges `x` and `['x3']` and build a new list. From now on, `x` is pointing the new object built. That's why you get a different id. Meanwhile `['x1', 'x2']` object is deleted because nothing is pointing that object because `x` is pointing the new object.